# Making a Variable Scale

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I am building a program that simulates physical phenomena (in particular, electric charges) in an arbitrary region (to make sense more sense, it should be somewhere around the picometre scale, but, still, the idea is to let the user play around a bit with the values, like trying to see charges interact over kilometres), using a Cairo draw area that is scaled to provide adequate zooming capabilities.

From a user's point of view, there should be a comfortable way to change the scale, both to large and small values, so what seems most logical to me is to create a gtk_scale whose adjustment value changes as the user gets closer to either edge. Now, I must confess I am not the most experienced programmer out here, quite on the contrary, so I apologize for any stupidity I may be making, but shouldn't the following code work?

```
gboolean scale_change(GtkWidget *w, gpointer p)
{
    pdata *data = (pdata *) p;

    //A struct with all the program data.

    double temp;
    data->scale = gtk_range_get_value(GTK_RANGE(data->vis_scale));

    //data->scale is the value used to later scale cairo.

    temp = log10(data->scale);
    if (temp - floor(temp + 0.5) < DBL_EPSILON)

    //Check if the value is a power of ten, to change the scale

    {
        data->sadj = gtk_adjustment_new( data->scale, 0.1*data->scale, 10.0*data->scale,
                                         data->scale, 1, (data->scale) * 
                                         max(gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(data->drawarea),
                                         gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(data->drawarea)));

        gtk_range_set_adjustment(GTK_SCALE(data->vis_scale), data->sadj);
        gtk_scale_set_digits(GTK_SCALE(data->vis_scale), (int) temp);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

But, since it isn't, is there a better way to do this, or is my idea outright impossible, or, at the very least, highly impractical?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GtkSpinButton and change its `range`. It would have the same effect without as much hassle...